# Ajax loop after success

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel-5.1

i have this json response

```
    [[{"id":73,"entry_by":"5","post":"Prova","location":"","images":"","tagged_friends":0,"created_at":"2016-08-05
 07:17:14","updated_at":"2016-08-05 07:17:14","post_type":0,"comments_open":0,"is_blocked":0,"is_share"
:0,"video":"","book_id":0,"author_id":0},{"id":72,"entry_by":"5","post":"Prova","location":"","images"
:"","tagged_friends":0,"created_at":"2016-08-05 06:59:18","updated_at":"2016-08-05 06:59:18","post_type"
:0,"comments_open":0,"is_blocked":0,"is_share":0,"video":"","book_id":0,"author_id":0},{"id":71,"entry_by"
:"5","post":"Prova","location":"","images":"","tagged_friends":0,"created_at":"2016-08-05 06:59:12","updated_at"
:"2016-08-05 06:59:12","post_type":0,"comments_open":0,"is_blocked":0,"is_share":0,"video":"","book_id"
:0,"author_id":0},{"id":70,"entry_by":"5","post":"Prova","location":"","images":"","tagged_friends":0
,"created_at":"2016-08-05 06:59:08","updated_at":"2016-08-05 06:59:08","post_type":0,"comments_open"
:0,"is_blocked":0,"is_share":0,"video":"","book_id":0,"author_id":0},{"id":69,"entry_by":"5","post":"Prova"
,"location":"","images":"","tagged_friends":0,"created_at":"2016-08-05 06:59:04","updated_at":"2016-08-05
 06:59:04","post_type":0,"comments_open":0,"is_blocked":0,"is_share":0,"video":"","book_id":0,"author_id"
:0},{"id":68,"entry_by":"5","post":"Prova","location":"","images":"","tagged_friends":0,"created_at"
:"2016-08-05 06:58:58","updated_at":"2016-08-05 06:58:58","post_type":0,"comments_open":0,"is_blocked"
:0,"is_share":0,"video":"","book_id":0,"author_id":0},{"id":67,"entry_by":"5","post":"Prova","location"
:"","images":"","tagged_friends":0,"created_at":"2016-08-05 06:58:51","updated_at":"2016-08-05 06:58
:51","post_type":0,"comments_open":0,"is_blocked":0,"is_share":0,"video":"","book_id":0,"author_id":0
},{"id":66,"entry_by":"5","post":"Prova","location":"","images":"","tagged_friends":0,"created_at":"2016-08-05
 06:56:58","updated_at":"2016-08-05 06:56:58","post_type":0,"comments_open":0,"is_blocked":0,"is_share"
:0,"video":"","book_id":0,"author_id":0},{"id":65,"entry_by":"5","post":"Prova","location":"","images"
:"","tagged_friends":0,"created_at":"2016-08-05 06:56:52","updated_at":"2016-08-05 06:56:52","post_type"
:0,"comments_open":0,"is_blocked":0,"is_share":0,"video":"","book_id":0,"author_id":0},{"id":64,"entry_by"
:"5","post":"MInkia","location":"","images":"","tagged_friends":0,"created_at":"2016-08-05 06:41:59"
,"updated_at":"2016-08-05 06:41:59","post_type":0,"comments_open":0,"is_blocked":0,"is_share":0,"video"
:"","book_id":0,"author_id":0},{"id":63,"entry_by":"5","post":"MInkia","location":"","images":"","tagged_friends"
:0,"created_at":"2016-08-05 06:41:51","updated_at":"2016-08-05 06:41:51","post_type":0,"comments_open"
:0,"is_blocked":0,"is_share":0,"video":"","book_id":0,"author_id":0},{"id":74,"entry_by":"5","post":"Prova"
,"location":"","images":"","tagged_friends":0,"created_at":"2016-08-05 07:17:32","updated_at":"2016-08-05
 07:17:32","post_type":0,"comments_open":0,"is_blocked":0,"is_share":0,"video":"","book_id":0,"author_id"
:0},{"id":75,"entry_by":"5","post":"Prova","location":"","images":"","tagged_friends":0,"created_at"
:"2016-08-05 07:18:28","updated_at":"2016-08-05 07:18:28","post_type":0,"comments_open":0,"is_blocked"
:0,"is_share":0,"video":"","book_id":0,"author_id":0}]]
```

i want to create a live feed masonry that show this result but in AJAX i fetch only the first result. This is Ajax (at the moment there is not output from Json i need only to get on div appended foreach result)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url:"getposts",
      type: "get",  
      data: "{}",
      success: function(data){
        var res = data;
        $.each(res, function(index, value) {
            $('#prova').append($('<div class="timeline-block">\
                  <div class="panel panel-default">\
                    <div class="panel-heading">\
                      <div class="media">\
                        <div class="media-left">\
                          <a href="">\
                            <img src="http://bookstar.me/uploads/users/paolo.jpg" width="50px" class="media-object">\
                    </a>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="media-body">\
                          <a href="#" class="pull-right text-muted"><i class="icon-reply-all-fill fa fa-2x "></i></a>\
                             <a href="">Paolo</a>\
                          <span>1/08/2016</span>\
                     </div>\
                      </div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="panel-body">\
                      <p>Prova</p>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="view-all-comments">\
                      <a href="#">\
                        <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> View all</a>\
                      <span>10 comments</span>\
                    </div>\
                    <ul class="comments">\
                      <li class="media">\
                        <div class="media-left">\
                          <a href="">\
                            <img src="http://bookstar.me/images/people/50/guy-5.jpg" class="media-object"></a>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="media-body">\
                          <div class="pull-right dropdown" data-show-hover="li">\
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="toggle-button">\
                              <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>\
                            </a>\
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">\
                              <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>\
                              <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>\
                            </ul>\
                          </div>\
                          <a href="" class="comment-author pull-left">Bill D.</a>\
                          <span>Hi Mary, Nice Party</span>\
                          <div class="comment-date">21st September</div>\
                        </div>\
                      </li>\
                      <li class="media">\
                        <div class="media-left">\
                          <a href="">\
                            <img src="http://bookstar.me/images/people/50/woman-5.jpg" class="media-object">\
                          </a>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="media-body">\
                          <div class="pull-right dropdown" data-show-hover="li">\
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="toggle-button">\
                              <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>\
                            </a>\
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">\
                              <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>\
                              <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>\
                            </ul>\
                          </div>\
                          <a href="" class="comment-author pull-left">Mary</a>\
                          <span>Thanks Bill</span>\
                          <div class="comment-date">2 days</div>\
                        </div>\
                      </li>\
                      <li class="media">\
                        <div class="media-left">\
                          <a href="">\
                            <img src="http://bookstar.me/images/people/50/guy-5.jpg" class="media-object"></a>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="media-body">\
                          <div class="pull-right dropdown" data-show-hover="li">\
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="toggle-button">\
                              <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>\
                            </a>\
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">\
                              <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>\
                              <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>\
                            </ul>\
                          </div>\
                          <a href="" class="comment-author pull-left">Bill D.</a>\
                          <span>What time did it finish?</span>\
                          <div class="comment-date">14 min</div>\
                        </div>\
                      </li>\
                      <li class="comment-form">\
                        <div class="input-group">\
                          <span class="input-group-btn">\
                   <a href="" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-photo"></i></a>\
                </span>\
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" />\
                        </div>\
                      </li>\
                    </ul>\
                  </div>\
                </div>'));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but I don't believe you're using `.append()` correctly. You don't need to build a JQuery object just to append it, you can pass a sting into the append, and I don't think the slashes at the end of each line will do what you're after (If you want a multi-line string in JS, I'd construct it as `"this"+"that"+"the other"` with a string for each line and a line break after each plus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This JSON is 13 arrays in an array. So try:

```
$.each(res[0], function(index, value) {...});
```

or your results are some arrays:

```
$.each(res, function(index, value) {
    $.each(value, function(index2, value2) {...});
});
```

I hope i help you

Comment: Great! Thanks, working as well. On other things if you can. Now how i can extract item from the array and use inside html? For example how i can use "post" array item and use in <p> tag?

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to flatten your array, since it is an array of one array of 13 objects.

That can be done by concatenating all of the elements in the inner array.

The [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) will take each element in the array it is called upon and create an argument of it. call(...[1,2]) is the same as call(1,2). Doing that on your result will remove the outer array.

Using [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) will then allow you to get an array to be able to call [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate through all your json values and create html to insert into your DOM.

```
[].concat(...res).forEach(function(values) {
   $('#prova').append(generateHtml(values));
});
```

Or less generally:

```
res[0].forEach(function(values){
   $('#prova').append(generateHtml(values));
});
```